# A verb for expelling mucus from nose with force

Tags: word-request

The winter is 'on', and we all are getting cold. Being a doctor, I know that if you don't expel the mucus accumulated in your nose, you are likely to get an infection. Anyway, facts aside, how do I instruct my daughter to expel the mucus from her nose with force?

Note that in this process, we close our mouth tightly and exhale air from the nose with force so it expels all the  mucus from there.

*(Yuk! But I need a verb!)*

I don't think [*sneeze*](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/sneeze_1?q=sneeze) is a good word. Because it's *involuntary* and it involves both the mouth and nose. But here, it involves only the nose.

'Clean your nose' also comes to my mind but then it is not necessarily blowing out air.

Not strictly a *verb*, I'm open to getting anything though - a noun, idiom etc.

Comment: To sternutate means to sneeze.

Comment: How about  "Farmer's blow" where there's no handkerchief or tissue, its just aimed at the ground.   Cyclists on a ride would call this "snotting"   and there's a whole ettiquette around it. http://www.sydneycyclist.com/forum/topics/spitting-snotting-etiquette  Yes its gross, but its a fact in any solid exercise.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think the idiom you're looking for is "to blow one's nose". Most people say "I need to blow my nose", or "please blow your nose", which means to expel mucus by voluntarily exhaling forcefully through the nose.

Comment: yes, it is! I firmly believed that 'blow someone's nose' would be some idiom and the literal meaning does not exist! Some times, little things turn out to be the major ones! :) +1 Thanks!

Comment: Also, see snot rocket: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snot_rocket

Comment: The snot rocket usually refers to blowing the nose without a tissue, by blocking one nostril at the time to clear the nose (into the air and onto the ground), for example when doing outdoor sports.

Comment: Snot rocket is what I came here to upvote. It deserves its own answer (now provided).

Comment: @Will I believe that's somewhat more colloquial.

Comment: I always thought that was called a "Brooklyn handkerchief".

Answer (score 4):

To blow one' s nose or to clear the nose

Answer (score 3):

Colloquially (when nothing is used to catch the mucus), this is known as a *snot rocket* . Which [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOswrh_3ea8) describes as, "A jet of mucus deliberately expelled from one's nostril." Seldom is the act of blowing one's nose done without a handkerchief or a tissue, but if you are you're doing *snot rockets*.

> Sorry, it's too late to go back and get some tissue. Just do a *snot rocket* and wipe what's left on your sleeve; I won't tell anyone.